# Continuous function on compact set attains its maximum and minimum.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> If $A$ is compact, prove that every continuous function $f\colon A\to \mathbb{R}$
> takes on a maximum and a minimum value.

**My attempt:** Since $A$ is compact and $f$ continuous $f(A)$ is also compact and hence closed and bounded. Moreover, the boundedness of $f(A)$
implies the existence of a supremum $s$ and infimum $l$. It remains to show that $s, l \in f(A)$. Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that
$s \in \mathbb{R}-f(A)$ so there is some $\epsilon>0$ s.t. $B_{\epsilon}\left(s\right) \subseteq \mathbb{R}-f(A).$ However, this would mean that
$(s-\epsilon / 2)\in \mathbb{R}-f(A)$ and $f(a)\le s-\epsilon / 2 < s$ for all $f(a)\in f(A)$. This contradicts the fact that $s$ is the supremum of $f(A)$. The argument for the infimum is analogous.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: $s$ should be in $\mathbb{R} \setminus f(A)$. However you can end the argument way more easily referring to a maximizing sequence and Bolzano-Weierstrass characterization of compacity.

Comment: @blamethelag ye, but is my solution correct apart from this?

Comment: No your $s$ is taken in the wrong set.

Comment: @blamethelag that's why I said **apart from this**? If it would be taken from the set you just mentioned, the idea stays the same.

Comment: Ok with $s-\epsilon/2 \in \mathbb{R} \setminus f(A)$ but not okay with what comes next. Even when replacing $a$ with $f(a)$.

Comment: @blamethelag ok, so why are you not okay with it?

Comment: Why should it be true? Also please edit your question it is very painful to deal with this nonsense.

Comment: @blamethelag I guess I will just define a sequence $(\epsilon_n)\to 0$ and $(a_n)$ with $s-\epsilon_n\le a_n \le s$ whereby $a_n \in f(A)$ and notice that $a_n \to s$. Because a closed set contains all its limit points we're done.

Answer (score 2):

I just rephrase your last comment in a more suitable way for the sake of clarity.

The set $f(A)$ is the continuous image of a compact so it is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$. It is thus bounded and admites both supremum and infimum. Let us show the supremum is reached in $A$. Denote the supremum $s$, by definition of the real supremum there exists a sequence $(y_n)$ of points of $f(A)$ converging to $s$. But then $f(A)$ being closed we have $s \in f(A)$.